# Free array syntax and defining malloc

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

I am trying to free an array only if it contains something but I am heading a problem probably with syntax, because my code stores data in that array and when I change the file which the array reads from, it has to free that array because if I would like to store those characters in there again, it would just add them, not overwrite them.
The problem is this error in compiler:  `0 [main] DNAA 2160 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to DNAA.exe.stackdump`

it does not work, I have no idea what is wrong.

```
void nacitanie(int *i, char *pole){
    //some code....

    int a, x=0;
    char z;
    //reading from file..
    //condition if contains data, free it before running again
    if (pole != NULL)
    {
        free (pole);
        pole = NULL;
    }

    while( (z = getc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        pole[*i] = z;
        (*i)++;
    }
    for(a=0; a<*i; a++){
        if(pole[a] == 'A' || pole[a] == 'C' || pole[a] == 'G' || pole[a] == 'T' || pole[a] == 'a' || pole[a] == 'c' || pole[a] == 'g' || pole[a] == 't'){
            x++;
        }else{
            x--;
        }
    }
    if(x==a){
        printf("Sekvenciu sa podarilo nacitat\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }else{
        printf("Sekvencia nesplna podmienky\n");
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    if(fclose(fp) == EOF)
    printf("Subor sa nezatvoril");
}
```

malloc is in main function, where is reading function called

```
 int main() {
    int i=0;
    char *pole = malloc(MAX);
  //vstup z klavesnice
    char c;
    while(1)
    {
      switch(c = getchar())
      {
          case 'v':
              trojica();
           break;

          case 'n':
              nacitanie(&i, pole);
           break;

          case 'h':
              histogram(&i, pole);

           break;
```

MAX is defined as 1000 characters for that array

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Your syntax to free the memory should be `if (pole != NULL) { free (pole); pole = NULL; }`

Comment: @WeatherVane that did not help. I have malloc defined as it is in the code I provided and I edited the free function and nothing just error.

Comment: @merlin2011, I updated problem description.

Comment: If you are running into what sounds like a compile-time error, please a full minimum working example that reproduces the error. You have posted two fragments which are insufficient to reproduce the error without the rest of the code.

Comment: `pole` is declared as a local variable in `main()` so you have to pass it to the function which frees it.

Comment: @merlin2011 here is more code

Comment: You free `pole` and set it to `NULL`, then you use `pole` right after (null pointer dereference).  I think you meant to CLEAR pole instead of free it: `memset(pole, 0, MAX);`

Comment: @JS1 thanks man, thats what I needed. Also I had to clear "i" variable in the code.